# Creating temporal functions with dynamically generated names in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, create-function

I have an external javascript file which is loaded dynamically, and it has an `oncomplete=` variable, which increases its value each time that it is called. For example:

- **First time**: external.js?oncomplete=sayHello1
- **Second time**: external.js?oncomplete=sayHello2
- **Third time**: external.js?oncomplete=sayHello3

Because of that I need to dynamically create functions to execute the oncomplete= callback each time. That means, that I need to create functions with these names:

- sayHello1();
- sayHello2();
- ...etc

This is my current code, which creates a specific name function:

```
var sayHello = function (){
    console.log('hello');
};
sayHello();
```

The question is: **How can I create temporal functions with dynamically generated names in jQuery?**

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? There might be a more straightforward way to approach the problem.

Comment: You can use `window` property notation: `window[func_name] = function () {...}`

Comment: @sholanozie since the external.js file is from another server, i have to follow their instructions. Each time a script is loaded, the oncomplete= value changes, and a function with oncomplete's value is executed (if it doesn't exist, it'll throw an error.

Comment: I guess your server is generating a javascript ending with `/*some stuff*/ sayHello1()`. If so, you might get inspiration from [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) to generate `/*someStuff*/ sayHello(1)`

Comment: Ok, I just seen that you don't have access to the server, then simply use  @hindmost's solution.

Comment: @Demurgos nop, the external server generates something with `sayHello1(response.object)`, where `sayHelloX` must change `X` on each call.

Comment: @hindmost quick question: how can I delete the function created inside `window[func_name]`, would it be enough with `window[func_name]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of a pure javascript question.  Assuming the global scope (window) for simplicity,

```
var sayHello = function () { /* body */ };
```

is equivalent to

```
window['sayHello'] = function () { /* body */ };
```

Now, obviously, you don't want to pollute the global scope like that, so you can do the same thing with any other object.

```
dynamicFunctions = {};

var oncomplete = 'sayHello1';
dynamicFunctions[oncomplete] = function () { console.log('hello'); };

dynamicFunctions[oncomplete]();
// outputs hello to the console
```

One thing to keep in mind, though, is why you're doing it this way in the first place.  As I'm not sure of your specific requirements, is there a reason that you can't do something like this?

```
// load external.js?oncomplete=sayHello&increment=4
sayHello(increment);
```

Comment: He does have to use the window namespace since the server responds with a JSONP - and he don't have access to the server.

Comment: @AkshayDhalwala Great approach. I'll answer your question first: Sadly, I can't send the count value as a parameter, mainly because of the tight requirements of the external server.

Comment: @AkshayDhalwala i'm trying to implement this solution, but there is a small problem. Since the response from the server will be `sayHello1(response.object)` ... it will throw an error because sayHello1() doesn't exist, what actually exists as per your code is `dynamicFunctions['sayHello1']()`

Comment: @AkshayDhalwala my main question is: what would be the problem of polluting the global scope? I can easily set `window['sayHello1'] = null` inside of `window['sayHello2']`, or would you advice against that practice?

Comment: ah, apparently I missed some of your requirements.  Doing window['sayHello1'] is just fine as well.  There's nothing actually wrong with putting everything in window; it just means that code is available everywhere and could potentially overwrite something or get overwritten.  Like if (for whatever reason) another plugin that you're using accidentally overwrites window['sayHello'].